# Images not showing up in PDF compile of thesis in Latex (via Overleaf)

Tags: image, latex

I have images inside a figures folder for my thesis. When I use the \includegraphics[]{} command in my chapterX.tex file, the image just won't appear (in normal mode, fast mode, or in the downloaded PDF). They seem to scale, but just won't appear.

I've tried using the graphicsx and graphics packages, but neither work.

```
\documentclass[
10pt, 
english, 
singlespacing, 
draft,
parindent 20mm
headsepline, 
chapterinoneline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{ctable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2} 
\setlength{\mtcindent}{24pt} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    }

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files




\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=3cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3cm, % Outer margin
    %bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Conceptual framework}

\label{Chapter3} 

\minitoc

\section{Introduction}

Below is Jackendoff's parallel architecture.

\includegraphics{figures/jackendoffpa.jpeg}
```

Comment: Can you show the .log file?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean with `They seem to scale, but just won't appear.`?

Comment: Can you try with `\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{jackendoffpa}`

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could include a link to your overleaf project

Comment: You should ask this at https://tex.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: When I change the scale of the image, the blank box (white, black border, with name of file inside) changes size.

Comment: I can't link to my project, it's my PhD thesis and contains my IP

Comment: This didn't work `\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{jackendoffpa}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `draft` option to see your images:

```
\documentclass[
10pt, 
english, 
singlespacing, 
%draft,
parindent 20mm
headsepline, 
chapterinoneline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{ctable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2} 
\setlength{\mtcindent}{24pt} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    }

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files




\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=3cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3cm, % Outer margin
    %bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Conceptual framework}

\label{Chapter3} 

\minitoc

\section{Introduction}

Below is Jackendoff's parallel architecture.

\includegraphics{jackendoffpa}

\end{document}
```

[image]